# Port Forwarding from domain1.com:25565 to 40000 and from domain2.com:25565 to 30000

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, domain-server

I have a Server running on port 30.000 and port 40.000 and if someone acess domain1.com:25565 he should connect to the local port 40.000 and if he connects over domain2.com:25565 he should connect with the local port 30.000

domain1.com:25565 -> 37.120.174.183:25565 -> localhost:40000

domain2.com:25565 -> 37.120.174.183:25565 -> localhost:30000

Comment: Please clarify: Do domain1.com and domain2.com resolve to the same IP address or to two different IP addresses. If they both resolve to the same IP address, then I don't know of a way to do what you want with iptables.

Comment: The IP addresses are the same...

Comment: Perhaps you could comment on what your application is. When you mentioned port 25565 I assumed it wasn't a web server application, but I see other answers based on it being a web server type application. I only mentioned the web server stuff to show, in that case, the distinction is done at a higher level.

Comment: It´s a Minecraft Server http://minecraft.net

Comment: Then I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the incoming packets attempting to initiate a connection wouldn't contain the destination domain name, only the destination IP address. Therefore there isn't enough information to create any iptables rules to redirect the packets. You can not do what you are trying to do.

Now, you might be aware that often web servers can deal with many different domains, all resolving to one IP address. That is done via the web server configuration, and not at the network packet level. Eventually, once the network connection has been established, the destination domain name is included and the web server can decide what actual pages the user is trying to access and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is not `iptables` solution but work :)

Solution is to use `apache` modules `mod_proxy.so` and `mod_proxy_http.so`

Install mod_proxy and setup reverse proxy in Apache Webserver

Install the module

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

Installing the dependency libxml2-dev

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Load the module

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Create the Virtual Host in apache configuration file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

Listen 40000
Listen 30000
<VirtualHost *:25565>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain1.com-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain1.com-error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        ProxyPass / http://domain1.com:40000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://domain1.com:40000/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:40000>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        #### This is where you put your files for that domain: /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:25565>
            ServerName domain2.com
            ServerAlias www.domain2.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com

            <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain2.com>
                    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-access.log combined
            ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-error.log
            # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.
            LogLevel warn

            ProxyPass / http://domain2.com:30000/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://domain2.com:30000/
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:30000>
            ServerName domain2.com
            ServerAlias www.domain2.com
            #### This is where you put your files for that domain: /var/www/vhosts/domain2.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain2.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

Now restart the apache

```
 /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Only is left to deny access with `iptables` for external network on ports `30000` and `40000` because `apache` use `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Although `mod-proxy` from Apache can work, the best solution for your problem is using a reverse proxy such as `haproxy`.

install `haproxy` by using this command:

`sudo apt-get install haproxy`

then edit the config file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/haproxy.cfg
```

put these lines in the config file

```
//Put this in the file
global
    daemon
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:25565
    acl is_site1 hdr_end(host) -i domain1.com
    acl is_site2 hdr_end(host) -i domain2.com

    use_backend site1 if is_site1
    use_backend site2 if is_site2

backend site1
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server s2 127.0.0.1:40000 maxconn 32

backend site2
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server s1 127.0.0.1:30000 maxconn 32

listen admin
    bind 127.0.0.1:8080
    stats enable
```

start/restart you server by using:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy.cfg -D -p /var/run/haproxy.pid
```

[source](http://oskarhane.com/haproxy-as-a-static-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers/)